# Android supporting different languages.

Tags: android

I have one android application supporting diff languages.
I have different versions of string for every language like.

values-aa, values-bb and values-cc etc.

But my application is not displaying strings in diff languages. 
I have done all the necessary thing for multiple language support but still some times app does not display text in diff. languages.

What can be the cause?

Comment: did you change your phone's language to test it?

Comment: I have one settings menu in my app which is used for changing language. which also calls "updateConfiguration" for setting locals.

Answer (score 14):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html); as stated:

**Create Locale Directories and String Files**

To add support for more languages, create additional values directories inside res/ that include a hyphen and the ISO country code at the end of the directory name. For example, values-es/ is the directory containing simple resourcess for the Locales with the language code "es". Android loads the appropriate resources according to the locale settings of the device at run time.

Once you’ve decided on the languages you will support, create the resource subdirectories and string resource files. For example:

> MyProject/
>       res/
>          values/
>              strings.xml
>          values-es/
>              strings.xml
>          values-fr/
>              strings.xml

Add the string values for each locale into the appropriate file.

At runtime, the Android system uses the appropriate set of string resources based on the locale currently set for the user's device.

For example, the following are some different string resource files for different languages.

English (default locale), /values/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">My Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello World!</string>
</resources>
```

Spanish, /values-es/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mi Aplicación</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hola Mundo!</string>
</resources>
```

French, /values-fr/strings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="title">Mon Application</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Bonjour le monde !</string>
</resources>
```

**Note**: You can use the locale qualifier (or any configuration qualifer) on any resource type, such as if you want to provide localized versions of your bitmap drawable. For more information, see Localization.

I guess that at first glimpse you have to change the folder names.

Comment: I have same implementation but when i changes language from the application then some of the text views are not reflecting the new language.

Comment: Please paste the `xml` for those (or some) of those text views and also, the corresponding `@string` resources that they visualize (as well as telling me in what folder are they situated). Thanks

Comment: My text view is this and `test_line1` is in diff language folders as described by you. \n  <TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/test_line1"
/>

Comment: For each language you should have ALL the string resources defined, even though you might not be using some of them, they will be used by the layout and they will take the value from the default language defind. This is where those strings take their values from.

Answer (score 0):

You have to handle and change the default phone Locale.
Imagine that you select the portuguese language (tag = "pt_PT"):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("pt_PT");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getApplicationContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Now when you do: `getString(R.string.YOUR_STRING_NAME)` it will return the string located at values-pt.

Remember to add this to your Manifest (in the activity that you whant to control the language):

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

Comment: After restarting activity after language change then after not seeing language change for some text views. don't know what causing this.

Comment: Try this before the code I've posted:
public void reload() {
     Intent intent = getIntent();
     overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
     intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
     finish();

     overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
     startActivity(intent);
 }

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy just try some step which is provided in this [link](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/multi-language-support-to-android-app)

Some code for reference

```
String languageToLoad = "hi"; // your language
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Its work. Best Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

In test you must change the device language to get the specific language of your app and the user to if he don't change the device language he will get the default language.